# Django not displaying template formatted time value

Tags: django, templates, time, tags, modelform

I have set up a model like so:

```
class Reoccurring(models.Model):
    Username = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field="username")
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Time = models.TimeField()
    DayOrDate = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Interval = models.ForeignKey(IntervalChoices, to_field="choice", default='Week')
```

and have set up my modelform like so:

```
valid_time_formats = ['%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p', '%H%p']

class ReoccurringForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReoccurringForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        ...

        self.fields['Time'] = TimeField(input_formats=valid_time_formats)
        self.fields['Time'].label = ''
        self.fields['Time'].widget.attrs.update({
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Time'
        })
```

as you can see I have the model set up as a timefield, and then reset it so that I can apply validation to it using some basic format strings. However the problem comes in when I am trying to display directly from the model into a template. I try to do this:

```
{{ item.Time }}
```

and I get the HH:MM:SS formatting displayed..so I try to use a tag to format it like so:
(TIME_FORMAT not set in settings)

```
{{ item.Time|time:"TIME_FORMAT" }}
```

or

```
{{ item.Time|time }}
```

or

```
{{ item.Time|time:'P' }}
```

and the time doesn't display at all!

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Does `{{ item.Time|time:"H:i" }}` work?

Comment: it does not, I cannot get any formats other than the default to work ):

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just didn't migrate the database correctly, as all my tests were finding the correctly formatted time, but it wasn't working on runserver. All is well, thanks!